# Transfer specific data from multiple sheets to one master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner at VBA and I would like your help,
I have a database that I continue to add new sheets with data from orders.
I want to make a master sheet that has the names of the sheets in a list and specific cells of them with automatic refresh each time I add sheets.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this out and works as expected (Sheet1 is supposed to be the Master Sheet):

```
Sub foo()
i = 0
For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then 'Do not include the Master Sheet
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = Ws.Name
        x = i
        Ws.UsedRange.copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B" & i)
        i = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For y = x To i
            Sheet1.Cells(y, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value
        Next y
    End If
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

For triggering the code when a new sheet is added:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    'put the code here
End Sub
```